# Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run a map/reducer in java. Below are my files

WordCount.java

```java
package counter;


public class WordCount extends Configured implements Tool {

public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("counterinput"));
    // Erase previous run output (if any)
    FileSystem.get(conf).delete(new Path("counteroutput"), true);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("counteroutput"));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
    return 0;
}   

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new WordCount(), args);
    System.exit(res);

    }
}
```

WordCountMapper.java

```java
public class WordCountMapper extends
Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text,IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("hi");
    String line = value.toString();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
        output.collect(word, one);
        }
    }
}
```

WordCountReducer.java

```java
public class WordCountReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values,
        OutputCollector<Text,IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("hello");
        int sum = 0;
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            sum += values.next().get();
        }
        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}
```

I am getting following error

```log
13/06/23 23:13:25 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with  
processName=JobTracker, sessionId=

13/06/23 23:13:25 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the 
arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/06/23 23:13:26 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/06/23 23:13:26 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
13/06/23 23:13:26 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/06/23 23:13:26 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
13/06/23 23:13:26 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
13/06/23 23:13:26 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
13/06/23 23:13:26 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local_0001
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, 
recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:845)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:541)
at org.
apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:124)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:621)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:305)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:177)
13/06/23 23:13:27 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/06/23 23:13:27 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
13/06/23 23:13:27 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0
```

I think it is not able to find Mapper and reducer class. I have written the code in main class, 
It is getting default Mapper and reducer class.

Answer (score 50):

Add these 2 lines in your code :

```
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```

You are using `TextOutputFormat` which emits LongWritable key and Text value by default, but you are emitting Text as key and IntWritable as value. You need to tell this to the famework.

HTH

Comment: I have those 2 lines in my main file

Comment: I can't see them..It's set"Map"OutputKeyClass

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I tried doing that. But it is still giving same error.

Comment: How are you running your job?

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE on ubuntu OS. I have 3 files as listed above. I right click on WordCount.java and Run as -> Run on Hadoop

Comment: Do one thing..Just export this project as a jar and add it to the same project itself. Rerun and see if it helps.

Comment: I have also added a sysout commands in mapper and reducer class. I dont see them getting printed either. I doubt if it is actually able to identify my mapper and reducer class.

Comment: Actually in that case it should throw classNotFound..Anyways just try what I have said and see if it works..We'll see then what to do

Comment: This is bad luck. We can't even switch to chat. Just write everything within a single class.

Comment: ohk. I will do that. Thanks anyways @Tariq

Comment: Just one off the topic help. You seem to have good knowledge and understanding of mapreduce. I have just started Map Reduce in hadoop. Would u suggest me some good book to start programming with map reduce which starts from basics??

Comment: I am still in the learning phase :). "Hadoop definitive guide"!

Comment: Ok. Even i am starting with that book :)

Comment: Yes. It did. I modified the code and used Context instead of outputCollector and Reporter in Mapper & reducer

Comment: Cool. Always prefer the new API.

Comment: Yes. Working out with new API

Answer (score 7):

This may not be your issue but I had this silly issue once. Make sure you are not mixing the old and the new libraries i.e. mapred vs mapreduce. Annotate @Overide on your map and reduce methods. If you see errors you are not properly overriding the methods.

Comment: thank you for this comment!  -In my case, the map() method signature was named mistakenly with capital letter: public void Map(..) Instead of public void map(...) - I was able to discover it using @Override-  Again, Tnx!

Answer (score 7):

I got a similar exception stack trace due to improper Mapper Class set in my code (typo :) )

```java
job.setMapperClass(Mapper.class)  // Set to org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper due to type
```

Notice that mistakenly I was using Mapper class from mapreduce package, I changed it to my custom mapper class:

```java
job.setMapperClass(LogProcMapperClass.class) // LogProcMapperClass is my custom mapper.
```

The exception is resolved after I corrected the mapper class.

Answer (score 2):

Removing this from Code solved the issue

```
super.map(key, value, context);
```