# Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mapper, bigdata

```
    package Sort;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
    public class sortmapper extends                  Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,DoubleWritable> {
        public void map(Text key, Iterable<DoubleWritable> value, Context                            context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line = value.toString();
            String subId = line.substring(15, 26);
            Double bytes = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(45, 56));
            if (bytes == null) 
                bytes = 0.0;
            context.write(new Text(subId),new DoubleWritable(bytes));
        }
    }
```

This is the mapper method I have written but I m getting the above error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262188/type-mismatch-in-key-from-map-expected-org-apache-hadoop-io-text-received-org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
  public class sortmapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,DoubleWritable> {
        public void map(Text key, Iterable<DoubleWritable> value, Context
```

**`Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,DoubleWritable>`**

For your mapper, the input key and value are:

```
LongWritable and Text
```

The output key and value are:

```
Text and DoubleWritable
```

And your `map()` signature should be:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
```