# Type mismatch in key from map as it identified as LongWriteable

Tags: java, hadoop

I wrote a MapReduce program to process the data from a text file. But when I run it locally (Linux VM), it hits an error that it identified the key from the map as a `LongWriteable` not `Text` as required by the `Mapper` class.

Log output:

```
2017-05-21 14:06:46,436 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
2017-05-21 14:06:46,454 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
2017-05-21 14:06:46,468 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Exception running child : java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1072)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1807)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:169)
```

And here's the code of my program.

Mapper:

```
public static class RepaymentMapper extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    public void map(Text key, Text values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        if(values.toString() != null) {
            try {
                String[] data = values.toString().split(DefaultValues.DATA_SEPARATOR);
                String repaymentDate = data[0];
                String accountNo = data[1];
                double repaymentAmount = Double.parseDouble(data[2]);
                double monthInstallment = Double.parseDouble(data[3]);
                double unCollectedAmount = 0;
                if(repaymentAmount == 0)
                    unCollectedAmount = monthInstallment;
                else if(repaymentAmount<monthInstallment)
                    unCollectedAmount = monthInstallment - repaymentAmount;
                output.collect(new Text(accountNo), new Text(repaymentDate + DefaultValues.DATA_SEPARATOR + String.valueOf(unCollectedAmount)));
            } catch(IOException io) {
                throw io;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
public static class RepaymentReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, DoubleWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
            try {
                for(Text v : values) {
                    String[] data = v.toString().split(DefaultValues.DATA_SEPARATOR);
                    output.collect(key,new DoubleWritable(Double.parseDouble(data[1])));
                }
            } catch(IOException io) {
                throw io;
            }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    try {
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Loan Repayment Job");
        job.setJarByClass(RepaymentAnalyticJob.class);
        job.setMapperClass(RepaymentMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(RepaymentReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262188/type-mismatch-in-key-from-map-expected-org-apache-hadoop-io-text-recieved-org

Comment: Mapper<LongWriteable, Text, Text, Text>

Comment: map(LongWriteable key, Text values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)